# Get user ID on every app server request

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-app-requests

I'm developing a FB app that is loaded in a FB canvas. I'm using Java with Spring as server side technology. On app load, FB requests with POST the URL that I have configured in the app account in FB, including `signed_request` param for user authorization. This way I can get the logged in user ID securely.

I wonder what is the best way to get the logged in user ID on each call from the HTML inside the canvas to my app web server (right after the signed_request call)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it as follows:

1. Authenticate the user once and get the `signed_request` param.
2. Store this in an internal map / database against the user.
3. Associate a [cryptographic nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) with every outgoing response which would come back along with the request and can be used to find the correct user.
4. All this happens in servlet filter (or its equivalent in Spring MVC if there is one) as this is a cross-cutting concern for all the incoming requests and outgoing responses.

My two cents!

Comment: Sounds very cumbersome for a simple task. What about setting a cookie with user details, then send it on each request, and validate it in server? FB is not providing any simpler way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Nonce is to prevent replay attacks which are possible with cookies. Moreover, HTTP being stateless, this responsibility will be left to the applications, though there may be libraries providing this functionality out-of-the-box. Not something facebook or any other app should provide.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get Facebook user ID if user hasn't authenticated the app. When user is authorised, the user id will always be passed with the `signed_request`.

Comment: I'm asking about every request since the user is authenticated and authorized.

Comment: If the user's already authorised, why not just store their user ID in a session variable along with the other details you'll need like their access_token?

Comment: I was just asking for the best way to do that. Hooking on the session can be one option, thanks.

Comment: @Igy is right. Any internal navigation shouldn't depend on Facebook anymore. The `signed_request` is meant to be saved in a session and re-validated only if an OAuth exception is thrown or in a similar scenario.

Comment: Well, then, this shouldn't have all the `facebook-*` tags.

Comment: I'm trying to look for a FB app specific solution. I guess every FB does that (identifies the requesting user).